# Pass only selected value as a param to an Api call from dropdown in Angular

Tags: angular, api

I'm calling an api passing param as user selects from given options. Problem is I want to pass that param only which is been selected by user and return corresponding result. 
Currently the api is returning results if all dropdowns are selected and not when only one dropdown is selected.

```
nextpage(){
this.httpClient.get('https://crm.c:3000/cal_lg', {
        params: {
          filter: '[["call_status","=","' + this.selectedType + '"],["partner_mobile","=","' + this.selectedUser + '"]]',
          pageNumber: '0',
          pageSize: '50'
        },
        observe: 'response'
      }).subscribe(users => {
   console.log(users);
})
} }
```

here's html code:

```
<select [(ngModel)] = "selectedType" allow-clear="true" (change)="nextPage()">
          <option *ngFor="let activity of filteredType"  [ngValue]="activity">{{activity}}</option>
      </select>

        <select [(ngModel)] = "selectedUser" (change)= "nextPage()" >
          <option *ngFor="let test of filteredUsers " [ngValue]="test">{{test}}</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: post your html code

Comment: added @Sajeetharan

Comment: You are passing the whole `activity` and `test` objects to `selectedType` and `selectedUser`. Is that what you want? Or do you want to pass some property of these objects?

Comment: The activity and test contain the values to be displayed in dropdown. Basically the APi  returns AND results and I want to perform OR.

Answer (score 0):

This resides in your Logic, you need to change the Logic according to your need. I guess the problem is here is since you are calling the same function for different dropdowns results are always going to be the latest one.

You can create two different API calls based on the selection of each drop-down, or add a if condition with the existing code

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But can you please give some example, I'm doing this for the first time .

Comment: you already have the code , just a matter of adding if condition or making a new function

Comment: Yup, but if I make different function for each drop-down and  they want result from both dropdowns combining , then how will I do this.

Comment: even if you use different functions, you are assigning the response back to same variable.

Comment: Okie I'll try this. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass Selected value to given method: **nextPage()**

```
<select [(ngModel)] = "selectedType" allow-clear="true" (change)="nextPage($event.target.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let activity of filteredType"  [ngValue]="activity">{{activity}}</option>
      </select>

        <select [(ngModel)] = "selectedUser" (change)= "nextPage($event.target.value)" >
          <option *ngFor="let test of filteredUsers " [ngValue]="test">{{test}}</option>
        </select>
```

this is one way where you can get current  selected value of option.
Might be it will help you for further API call.

Comment: No, this is not the problem. I'm getting the selected value. Problem is I want to pass params in api call corresponding to selected value and return result even if one param is selected.

Comment: $event.target.value also causes unresolved variable error in the template - how would you deal with that?